# Conditional Ribbon Tab Label based on Office version

Tags: vb.net, excel, visual-studio-2008, ms-word, powerpoint

Developing an addin for Microsoft Office 2007 onwards (client requirements, yuck) but I am rusty with my VB. I am using Visual Studio 2008 to create the addin for all 3 major programs; Word, Excel and PowerPoint.

I was wanting to set a condition to rename the Tab inside of the Ribbon depending on what version of office they were running. But I have searched everywhere and cannot seem to find a way to accomplish this? I don't quite understand what Ribbon XML is and how it differs from the visual designer.

It would be great to get some explanation of how to access elements of the Ribbon and change them depending on the Application Version (whenever I try to reference Application.Version VB doesn't seem to know what I am talking about)

I can clarify more however any help including 'where to look' would be much appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: I'm not sure how much VBA and .Net/COM add-ins differ, but in VBA, you'd define the UI via RibbonXML, which can do things like calling a routine in your code to get a name for a button/tab rather than hardcoding it in the XML.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I did, worked great. Thank you :)